# images leave there place after on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

Well there is a very wiered issue with my website, I don't know what is the reason. i have `hyperlinks` on images, but when I click on images, they leave their place. i am sharing a screen shot for better understanding.

**Before Click**

[image: Before Clickl]

**After Click**

[image: After Click]

Kindly tell me what else I have to share. As I on't know the reason so I am not sharing any css or js
Regards

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS/JS and a fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no way to diagnose this issue from a screenshot. Run Firebug or your browser's built-in development tools to narrow down the issue or at least find only the CSS and JS that touch the elements in question.

Comment: At least post the click handler for the images. Since you are not sharing any code, there is no way for us to debug your issue

Comment: My best suggestion is to look through the inspect element panel on Chrome browser to find out which declaration is causing this issue

Comment: My guess shooting from the hip is that the active state for `a` tag has a border around it. Open up the inspector in Chrome or Firefox and take a look at the element to see what changes.

Comment: Yes @BOMEz it some how creates a press affect when clicked, how to avoid that? As it also creates border around the other `a`. but there is no border assignes in my css to `a:active` for all

Comment: My best guess shooting from the hip is that this is actually wanted behaviour added by the creator.

Comment: Try explicityly setting `a:active{border: none!important;}`

Comment: From the picture, I would not say it can be caused by adding a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this fixed it in the comments I'll post here so others know. When an image starts jumping around when clicked it means that there is most likely a border around the `active` state. To fix it simply set :

```
a:active{border: none!important;} //!important may be overkill
```

The same holds true for if it dances around when you hover over it